# Can someone explain me why we use parentheses around conditions in javaScript

Tags: javascript

for an example if we take the below code Ex:

```
if (5 > 4) {}
```

in the above code I need to know why we use parentheses around the `if` statement's condition we can just use the below code like

```
if 5 > 4 {}
```

but why do we include parentheses around the `if` statement's condition for what purpose do we use it is it just to separate the condition and the `{}` block of the if statement or what

Comment: because Brendan Eich said so

Comment: because the language requires it

Comment: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/parentheses.html

Comment: Plus in longer `if` statements it helps with readability and order or precedence.

Comment: because of the standard ECMA 262.

Comment: for what purpose though there must be a reason to use parentheses around the condition

Comment: it helps readability and that's how Javascript was made. Why don't there is `; ` in python ?

Comment: @Kevin You use parentheses around the condition because you must. The language's syntax requires it. If you're asking why the language's syntax was designed that way, 0.sh's answer is about the best any of us know.

Comment: this is a good question, I have the same issue, but opposite: my "native" programming language is C, so I am fully okay with syntax of Java, JavaScript, PHP and many other languages. However when I started working with python I was scared :-)

Comment: If you have more then one condition in if will work only with parentheses around the if like if (1<2&&2>0)

Comment: @Oleg what do yu mean

Comment: Will be errors in more than one conditions without parentheses

Comment: I would guess it made JavaScript "look and feel" more like Java, which was a design goal (note the name but no real lineage with Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use parentheses around the condition because you must. The syntax of javascript demands that for if statements, the condition is wrapped in parentheses. Leaving them out is a syntax error.

If you're asking why the language was designed to have that particular syntax instead of some other, none of us were in the room when that decision was made. So about the best we can offer you is the answer 0.sh gave in the comments: "because Brendan Eich said so". Brendan Eich was the original creator of the javascript, and so he laid the foundations of its syntax. Whatever his motivations were for this decision, that's the reason it is that way.

It's possible to design languages so that the parentheses are optional, but that's just not the way javascript was designed.

Comment: if so pls explain me how the statement and condition is seperated of an if statement

Comment: I have no idea what information you're looking for.

Comment: i need to know how the condition and the code block of the above given if statement is seperated